# vlc wont autoplay cds and dvds but can play them in media

Tags: vlc, dvd, cd, autoplay

fresh install of popos 22.04 with vlc 3.0.18.

vlc will play dvds and cds manually by going to media > open disk > selecting the disc type (dvd / cd / bluray) then disk device ( /dev/cdrom ) that works but it wont autoplay cds or dvds when inserted, it throws the error "your input cant be opened, unable to open mrl cdda:///run/user/1000/gvfs/cdda:host=sr0"

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Unfortunately, Pop_OS is not supported on this site. Please review to the Help Center for off-topic issues: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.